# Dpad for sprite kit

Tags: sprite-kit

I an interested in trying to create a few games, namely in the new sprite kit. However, for the game that I have in mind I would rather use a directional pad vs a joy stick. Since I shall be moving over from Cocos, my old program no longer works (so neither will that dpad). Sadly, I have not come accross any tutorial that may help with implementing one in the new sprite kit (only joy sticks). I was wondering and hoping if anyone came across a simple dpad class from github or something or a helpful link that they would like to share. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
//Joystick node
- (SKSpriteNode *)controlPadNode
{
    SKSpriteNode *controlPadNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"game-controller-front"];
    controlPadNode.position = CGPointMake(controlPadX,controlPadY);
    controlPadNode.name = @"controlPadNode";
    controlPadNode.zPosition = 1.0;
    return controlPadNode;
}

//handle touch events
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    //if control pad touched
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"controlPadNode"]) {
        touchX = location.x;
        touchY = location.y;
        controlButtonDown = true;
    }
}

//when touch moves
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    //if control pad touched
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"controlPadNode"]) {
        touchX = location.x;
        touchY = location.y;
        controlButtonDown = true;
    }
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    //if control pad touched
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"controlPadNode"]) {
        controlButtonDown = false;
    }
}

//update method
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

    if (controlButtonDown) {

        //the control pad
        SKNode *controlNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"controlPadNode"];

        //the node you want to move
        SKNode *node = [self childNodeWithName:@"spaceShipNode"];

        //compute the angle between parameters pad and the horizontal
        float angle = atan2f (touchY - controlPadY, touchX - controlPadX) ;

        //move the control pad for the player to have a sense of movement
        SKAction *moveControlPad = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(touchX, touchY) duration:0.00001];
        double distance = sqrt(pow((touchX - controlPadX), 2.0) + pow((touchY - controlPadY), 2.0));

        //make sure the control pad only moves 40 pixels
        if( distance < 40 ){
            [controlNode runAction:moveControlPad];
        }

        //move the ship
        SKAction *moveShip = [SKAction moveByX: 6*cosf(angle) y:6*sinf(angle) duration:0.005];
        [node runAction: moveShip];        

    }
}
```

EDIT:

Also can use this to move the control pad back when touch ends:

```
if (!controlButtonDown) {
    SKNode *controlNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"controlPadNode"];
    SKAction *moveControlPad = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(controlPadX, controlPadY) duration:0.00001];
    [controlNode runAction:moveControlPad];
}
```

Comment: I've been fitting this in but im getting four errors on controlButtonDown not exactly sure how to handle that. And also initialized touchX and touchY like this till the location is passed in. (acceptable?)
float touchX = 0.0;
float touchY=0.0;

Comment: What errors are you getting with controlButtonDown? I'm assuming you declared it as BOOL controlButtonDown? touchX and touchY are good.

Comment: No i hadn't (made a silly mistake ). i made these two changes
 //touchY = 0; 
and  float angle = atan2f (0, touchX - controlPadX) ;
 (Cause i only want the spirte to move left or right). However if i click like towards the top of the centre of the dpad (hope i explained that ok) it still moves up

Comment: if you only want it to move left or right, you don't need any of the angle stuff,  just work out whether the touch is to the left or right of the control pad center and move the sprite accordingly

Comment: I did something really lazy. 
SKAction *moveShip=[SKAction moveByX:6*cosf(angle) y:0 duration:0.005];

Answer (score 3):

I've built a small UIKit based game engine before the introduction of SpriteKit. My engine loads cocos2d compatible maps from [Tiled](http://mapeditor.org), sprites from [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker), and *it comes with a joystick* that I ported from cocos2d to UIKit. (Mine is based on sneaky-joystick.)

You can [grab the whole library on GitHub](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBTileParser) and pull out the parts you need. It's fairly modular.

Comment: yea mine was sneaky joystick, will it work nicely? seeinf sprite kit is new and all