# Is there a work-around for CPU-Expensive (frame.contains)?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm building my first game with Swift and SpriteKit and I recently took the whole thing apart to determine where my CPU woes were coming from (~80-100% within a few minutes of game play). I recently discovered that one of the most expensive operations is located in the `touchesMoved` method. This isn't super surprising, because it is called very frequently and the user has their finger down the whole game to control the main character. However, I was surprised to find that one line in particular was causing the trouble. Here is my code:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch : AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        let touchStartPoint:CGPoint = startingTouches[touch as! UITouch]!

        if(controlBase.frame.contains(touchStartPoint)){
            controlStick.position = location
        }
    }

}
```

I ran 4 separate tests with Instruments each with another line. I found that without

```
   if(controlBase.frame.contains(touchStartPoint)){
        controlStick.position = location
    }
```

I was hovering at ~5-10% CPU while my finger was down-- so `touchesMoved` was still being called. However, when doing the check `if(controlBase.frame.contains(touchStartPoint)){`, even with nothing inside the brackets, I would hit ~20-30% CPU.

Here is a screenshot of what the setup currently looks like on iPhone:
[image]

and here is a picture of my Instruments log: the low points are when my finger is lifted from screen and high points when my finger is moving the controller.[image]

Is there anyway to address this issue? I'm doing this check to ensure that the handle on the users virtual joystick cannot leave its base. I'm just not sure why this one line would be so expensive and if this is inherent to this check, if there is another way to achieve similar functionality. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd be worried about this. Based on your instruments log, you are not using a lot of CPU. You'll note that rendering is your highest consumer, not your code for touch. Unless you need to scroll dow more to expose it. Try to use the CPU Dashboard in Xcode on your next run and see how those numbers fare. Also what is your FPS?

Comment: Really? On Xcode they sugggest 20% I believe, unless you're saying that if FPS isn't effected heavily there's not much to worry about? My FPS is steadily 60 until later in the game (couple minutes) when it degrades to low 40s-- also this example doesn't account for full gameplay, only the controller (this is a separate project where I'm rebuilding the app)

Comment: Now try running Spaceships and see it's CPU usage (minus the few minutes later). If your touch code was consuming a lot, you'll see it show up in the call tree in a higher position, which it is not. I'd say make progress on your other stuff and revisit. Let FPS be your guide. In the end you'll most likely end up with a high CPU usage game, unless you're making something like tic tac toe ;). Obviously the drop-off indicates you have other challenges ahead.

Comment: Oh yeah, it is still probably useful to have something that can descend your tree and give accurate counts just in case you need a tally. Code like that comes in handy.

Comment: This is what happens when non-game-engine companies (so: Apple) have a little go at making game engines.  :/

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, okay, I just saw this after I left some comments for you in another thread. You are a bit at the mercy of the OS in regards to the frequency of touch events you get. It's up to you to try and limit the bandwidth taken up during these moments.

The question here is just how large is your node tree? It may be useful to temporarily add some code to physically count the number of nodes by manually walking down the tree. Are you also applying scale and rotate on nodes and using hierarchy? If so, you should note that too as it will require more computation.

Still based on what you have previously described, I'd be surprised if this was really eating up your bandwidth (given you said you have 20 objects).

Alternatively if you really want you can create your own contains. That is actually what I do, however part of this is a byproduct of having special needs with how I deal with my graphics. That being said, I have hundreds of objects I go through and I don't have noticeable issues. Note that I am not scrutinizing CPU usage like you are. I only focus on FPS.

What is your FPS during this time? Also you should run this on the device and see what your CPU/GPU usage is relative to the frame. %CPU can also be a bit dubious I feel based on other factors like if you are logging or even at times, what else is going on with the OS.

Lastly try and move your code to the spaceship example and note the effects as you add more spaceships.

> Added Details

So when I was originally answering the questions I was taking less account into what you were doing. I still believe that you shouldn't be overly trying to optimize down here at this point, however looking at SKOOP's answer and in particular

https://github.com/MitrophD/Swift-SpriteKit-Analog-Stick

which is interesting code, gave me a better idea on what you really want to do and how you could squeeze out CPU usage if needed. One of the tenets behind game coding and optimizing is laziness. "How can I pre-compute or do the least amount of work?"

Here you would need to have some adjustment to you your `touchesBegin` and `touchedEnd`/`touchesCancelled`. In your class that is doing the touch processing add a member property called

`var controllerTouch : UITouch?`

Note this is optional and will represent the current touch that is in the controller. Also note that if you are doing multi-touch you are defining this as a rule: the first touch within the controller is the controlling one.

This brings up another key point, which are rules. You need to define rules. Here I am going to say it is okay for the touch of an active controller to go beyond the bounds of the `controllerBase` (this will be like maxing out the stick) and also that the controller should be actually a circle. Lastly, I am going to assume the `controllerBase` is static.

This now leads me to methods I can do to minimize the work needed.

**`touchesBegin`**

Since this is static, I should use simple maths for this by comparing the location of the touch to the distance from the center of the `controllerBase`. I can do this because we are saying this is a circle. So I should know the radius. Thus my check would be something like:

```
let distance = computeDistance(pt0: controllerBaseCenter, pt1: location)

// We only care about doing this if we are not currently actively tracking
if controllerTouch == nil {
    if distance < controllerBaseRadius {
        // Where touch is the current touch
        controllerTouch = touch
    }   
}
```

Note code is not tested for compilation or if it works, rather it is an example for what to do and assumes you'll fix it up as needed. I am assuming you will replace `computeDistance` with the correct maths to compute distance, which is a trivial thing to do. Also your distance needs to absolute.

One other thing to keep in mind. Since `controllerBase` is static, you can pre-compute and store in variables the actual center point (`controllerBaseCenter` and radius. This protects you from having to do `location` or `contains` on the node and hence saves wasted cycles each time `touchesStart` is run.

**`touchesEnd`/`touchesCancelled`**

Here you will nil out `controllerTouch` ***if*** it is the touch that is ended/canceled. If necessary, you can do any other logic for notification as well.

The real thing to deal with then is

**`touchesMoved`**

So here we know we already know if we have an active controller via `controllerTouch`

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch : AnyObject in touches {

        if touch == controllerTouch {
            // Only get location when needed (ie defer until you really need this)
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            controlStick.position = location // You will need to adjust, see notes below to compensate for controllerBaseCenter if needed
        }
    }
}
```

Note my defer comment. In your original code, you only should have done that `location` assignment when needed, which was when the touch was in `controllerBase.frame`.

Now, one last thing which I have omitted. It will be up to you how you want to treat the radial distance the controller can move. For example, if the radius is 64 and my touch starts at a distance from the center of 60, how is that treated? Do you treat that offset as the center point? If this is the case you need to track location of the first touch too to properly adjust the maths.

Keep in mind you need to make it easy for the player to not have to be precise. Also bear in mind they will not be frequently looking down at the controller area to double check things.

Comment: Just for clarification, as I was vague-- the game play is structured such that there is only one spaceship that is user controlled and the many objects are aliens that the spaceship (user) shoots at. That said, I'm not even drawing a spaceship to screen-- just getting values in game as I have `touchMoved` being called. The number of nodes should be around 3- the nodes making up the virtual game controller- A SKSpriteNode for the base (just a gray rectangle in the corner of the screen), a SKSpriteNode for the joyStick- just a red dot that follows under your finger (if finger is inside the base)

Comment: I am not quite sure you mean by your last comment. Anyways, "The number of nodes should...". The key word here is should. It always pays to validate just in case. Stranger things have happened. Do you happen to be doing anything in the background or are you logging your touches? If you truly have only 3 nodes descending from `controlBase.frame` it should be fast.

Comment: Oh and how are you measuring CPU usage? Using the CPU Dashboard? Try isolating this with spaceships.

Comment: And one other thing I thought of is you can just add nodes one by one onto `controlBase.frame` and see what happens.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the base/handle set up and also my Instruments log. I'll add some code to get a recursive count now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I implemented this in its entirety. However, with constant movement of the controller the game still goes up to 24-26% but immediately drops to 1% when there is no movement or the control finger is lifted?

Comment: @Sam, you need to chillax on this issue. I'd say at this point you have blinders on and are overly obsessed with CPU usage. I've been repeating the same items on: "have you tried spaceships with your code and measured usage" and "you should probably move on to other items and revisit if necessary". If you are really curious, you can run Time Profiler with moving your finger for say the vast majority of time of the session. Then look at the breakdown. From your instruments you included (old stuff), the input was not the issue. Again, this is repeating what I already pointed out.

Comment: Making a game is a war of attrition in many respects. You're just wasting time and energy (in this case not just your's but other's people time as well). It is possible that Time Profiler normalizes things at some point for CPU usage derivation. Anyways, I could go on, but that is Pandora's Box. At this point, provided you implemented what I discussed and are no longer doing any `location` or `contains` in the `touchesMoved` you are doing very little in the call. Keep in mind some of the OS underworking are also going to be grouped in the CPU usage. Move forward.

Comment: I completely got it-- I'm focusing on UI for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the mind bending aspects of dealing with Apple Frameworks.

NO GOOD MICRO EXAMPLES!

Many game engines and frameworks provide a litany of small, functional, pertinent examples, sometimes hundreds of them, showing how to use various aspects of the engine's functionality.

These are then (also) used as unit-like tests, for each iteration of the engine, and updated accordingly. Some of Apple's Sprite Kit demo code is in its original form.

And there's very little community.

So you're best off examining how others have done similar things on github, unfortunately, because there's not even a "best practices" document from Apple for Sprite Kit.

Here's a virtual joystick example on github.

https://github.com/MitrophD/Swift-SpriteKit-Analog-Stick

There's an interesting question here: [Dpad for sprite kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152523/dpad-for-sprite-kit)

in which the conditional is about the name of the node touched, rather than searching in the .frame

```
//if control pad touched
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"controlPadNode"]) {
       ....
    }
```

It could be that the search within the .frame is expensive. It (should be) simple maths, so I don't know why it would be, but then there's lots of weird gotchas with SpriteKit and SceneKit.

Comment: From a more holistic point of view, once you've identified a touch, and since you're only using the one touch for all movements of your space ship, I'm not sure you need a conditional to check what is being touched. You could (possibly) just assume it's on the screen, and use it's relative position in each move to control your ship.

Comment: "Many game engines..."  APPL is a stock which makes 32 cent headphones branded to 200 dollars using a logo and TV ads [full analysis](http://www.huffingtonpost.in/entry/we-took-apart-some-beats-headphones_b_7639618) - God Bless them, I encourage you to buy APPL stock. The idea of APPL trying their hand at a game engine is - cute!  Poor Dears!  (Remember the "map" thing.  Heh!)

Comment: "This is one of the mind bending aspects of dealing with Apple Frameworks." Just one. ONLY one. There's many. I'm sure you can list them. Other parts are their sheer greed, rampant cynicism, WWDC video pacing and presentation, their documentation as a whole, etc etc etc. Suggest a better game engine, darling, please!